# JUnit to check if new API contains enum

Tags: java, junit, enums

Im new to unit testing and I want to check if new API contains specified enum. What should I change instead of `is(true)` because now it's returning boolean but I need List?

Enum class:

```
public enum SupportingColor
{
    GREEN,
    BLACK
}
```

Supporting color method:

```
public List<SupportingColor> supportingColor() {
    return configuration.supportingColor();
}
```

Test case:

```
    @Test
    public void NEW_API_hasBlack() {
        ApiVersionFeatures features = ApiVersionFeatures.getByApiVersion(ApiVersion.NEW_API);

        assertThat(features.supportingColor(), is(true));
    }
```

Comment: probably `assertThat(features.supportingColor(), org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.hasItem(SupportingColor.BLACK));`

Comment: Thanks! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
assertThat(actual, Matchers.contains(SupportingColor.BLACK, SupportingColor.GREEN));
```

There are other variants of `contains` in `[Matchers][1]`. Go through the API docs

Answer (score 0):

you should invoke ListAssert.contains method instead

```
@Test
public void hasBlack() {
    List<SupportingColor> colorList = Arrays.asList(SupportingColor.BLACK, SupportingColor.GREEN);
    Assertions.assertThat(colorList).contains(SupportingColor.BLACK);
}

public enum SupportingColor {
    GREEN,
    BLACK
}
```